# OpenGL Cylinder

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm triying to show axes with 3 cylinders with 3 different colors. Here is my code;

```
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(0,1,0);
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
GLUquadricObj *obj = gluNewQuadric();

glRotated(90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
gluCylinder(obj, 1.0, 1.0, 10, 30, 30);

glEnd();

glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
```

when I change the "glColor3f(0,1,0);" values its color change, but I couldn't achive the change axis of cylinders. It is always on z-axis. When I change "glRotated(90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);" values its still represented on Z axis. I have also tried glRotatef function but it doesn't work neither. Which function should I use to change a cylinder's axis.

Comment: I know there is just 1 cylinder in the code but I will make it 3 after achiving rotation

Comment: It's probably offtopic, but as far as I know glBegin/glEnd and friends, also known as fixed pipeline, is depracted. You should **probably** try to learn something a bit newer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never call `gluCylinder` inside a `glBegin()/glEnd()` block. There is only a small subset of GL commands allowed there, `glColor` being one of them. `glRotate` though is not (and will just generate a GL error and will be ignored). Remove that `glBegin()/glEnd()` pair from your code and the rotation will actually work.